# set system variable in cmd but still can not find it

Tags: python

My system is Windows 10. I want to use `pip` in my command line so I need to set the System variables first. I input `setx PATH "%PATH%;C:\Python27\Scripts"` and get following information:

```
WARNING: The data being saved is truncated to 1024 characters.

SUCCESS: Specified value was saved.
```

It seems I successfully add the system variables. And then I enter `pip install scipy-0.17.0-cp35-none-win_amd64.whl` in my command line and still get the error:

```
'pip' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Why does this happen? Could someone explain to me which step failed and caused the error?

Comment: Did you search? http://superuser.com/questions/387619/overcoming-the-1024-character-limit-with-setx

Comment: Did you close you command prompt, open a new one, and then try to run `pip` after that?

Comment: echo `%PATH%`.  Don't you think that WARNING might be relevant?